# Ceva's theorem on one triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In triangle $ABC$, $AD,BE,CF$ are concurrent lines. $P,Q,R$ are points on $EF,FD,DE$ such that $DP,EQ$ and $FR$ are concurrent. Prove that $AP,BQ,CR$ are also concurrent.

I tried to apply [Ceva's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem), but since the endpoints of the cevians are in separate triangles, I got nowhere.

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Comment: The cevian's nest theorem is an extension of the ceva's theorem.

Comment: OK, so the answer to the query in my previous comment is: No (and would not be bothered to, ever).

Comment: Re: *How is this of topic?* If you follow the link in the big banner added after the question was put on hold, you will get to the FAQ about [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)? In this case the [part about context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) is relevant. @ParclyTaxel edited your post, I suppose that the intention was to add context. If you have something more to add, please, edit the post further. (That might improve chances of reopening.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true due to the Cevian's Nest Theorem. You can check the proof of it [here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h6579).